# Gulp-useref: conditionally process assets by type?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, gulp-useref

When using gulp-useref, is it possible to conditionally process the css & js assets depending on the html build type declared inside the html tags?

```
<!-- build:<type>(alternate search path) <path> -->
... HTML Markup, list of script / link tags.
<!-- endbuild -->
```

What I would like to do is only autoprefix and jslint the non-vendor assets by differentiating them, like that (notice css vs css_vendors types):

*index.html*

```
<!-- build:css_vendors css/vendors.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css css/styles.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

*gulpfile.js*

```
gulp.task('useref', function() {
  return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(useref({
      css: [ autoprefixer(), minifyCss() ],
      css_vendors: [ minifyCss() ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

But unfortunately, this gulpfile.js code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is another plugin that seems to function in the way you want, but I am unfamiliar with its use - [gulp-html-replace](https://github.com/VFK/gulp-html-replace).

With useref you can use gulp-if to apply function to a match:

```
.pipe($.if('*.css', autoprefixer()))
```

etc.

Though it seems that the source you are using is not sufficient for what you want to do, as you need to gather the assets from the html file. Example from my task, if you want:

```
gulp.task('build-dist', ['wiredep'], function () {

    var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ''});
    var cb = Math.random();

    return gulp
        .src(config.indexFile)
        .pipe($.rename(config.outputIndexFile))
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe($.if('*.css', $.csso()))
        .pipe($.if('**/lib.js', $.uglify({preserveComments: 'license', mangle: false})))
        .pipe($.if('**/init.js', $.ngAnnotate()))
        .pipe($.if('**/init.js', $.uglify({mangle: false})))
        .pipe($.if('**/app.js', $.ngAnnotate()))
        .pipe($.if('**/app.js', $.uglify()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.replace('.css"', '.css?cb=' + cb + '"'))
        .pipe($.replace('.js"', '.js?cb=' + cb + '"'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation))
        ;
});
```

Edit: `$` is `var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});` - used to avoid writing "require" all the time. :)

Comment: This will not work for gulp-useref version 3 (last version with *assets* method is 2.1.0)

Comment: Expected, but good point, thanks. Planning to rebuild the pipeline once Gulp 4 is out and stable.

Comment: It should be easy in your case - just replace *assets* with *useref()*, and remove *assets.restore()* and *useref()* below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way to do this is to use gulp-usemin instead of gulp-useref. Like that:

*index.html*

```
<!-- build:css_vendors css/vendors.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css_styles css/styles.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

*gulpfile.js*

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {   
   return gulp.src('index.html')
     .pipe(plumber())
     .pipe(usemin({
       css_vendors: [ minifyCss() ],
       css_styles: [ autoprefixer(), minifyCss() ]
     }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')); });
```

Comment: but note that usemin is blacklisted:  https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json